# Unexpected results using JSONArray.put(String) from BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

I'm getting unexpected results from `JSONArray.put(String)`.

My code:

```
public JSONArray readedID = new JSONArray();

public void load() throws IOException, JSONException {
    String FILENAME = "news";
    String line;
    InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        readedID.put(line);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    Log.d("vk", "news.readedID: "+readedID);
    TextView res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    res.setText("readedID: "+readedID);
}

public void save() throws IOException {
    String FILENAME = "news";
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(news.loadedID.toString().getBytes());
    fos.close();
}

// Fill loadedID
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
    loadedID.put(json.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString());
}
```

Here is `loadedID`:

```
["3316","3336","3335","3331","3327","3326","3319".... ]
```

So this is what I would expect from `readedID`:

```
["3316","3336","3335","3331","3327","3326","3319" .... ]
```

But this is what I get:

```
["\"3316\",\"3336\",\"3335\",\"3331\",\"3327\",\"3326\",\"3319\" .... "]"]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show us a short version of the content of your file.

Comment: replace `readedID.put(line);` with `readedID = new JSONArray(line);`

Comment: I don't believe that is your result `readedID`. You should be missing a `[` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... this \ is because you make a List Item to a String.

Now each " turns into a \" so that it is a char.

Simply just replace the old JSONArray with a new one:

```
readedID = new JSONArray(line);
```

Or maybe you can add an item if you want.

(Sorry for the writing mistakes, I'm on my smartphone)